# Create a nested list by different number of separators(but the same)

Tags: python

I have a word list like this:

```
river
mississippi
water
spain
cairo


hellow
kind
words
sentences
```

They are separated by different number of '\n'

What I want to do is to put these words which separate by one '\n' in an inner list, and the words which separate by **more than one** (could be 2,3 or more) '\n' in different inner list like this:

```
[['river', 'mississippi', 'water', 'spain', 'cairo'], ['hellow','kind','words','sentences']]
```

I tried

```
infile=open(test_sets_file,'r')
readed=infile.readlines()
newlist=[]
new_nestedlist=[]
for i in range(len(readed)):
    if readed[i]!='\n':
        new_nestedlist.append(readed[i].strip('\n'))
    else:
        newlist.append(new_nestedlist)
        new_nestedlist=[]
return newlist
```

it doesn't work
My code cannot print anything when the input text is

```
river
mississippi
water
spain
cairo
```

I know it is because I initialized the list as an empty one when meet a '\n'

I also found another question 
[Creating nested list from string data with two delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001912/creating-nested-list-from-string-data-with-two-delimiters-in-python)

about creating nested list by different separators, but it cannot solve my question

Comment: Please expand on *"doesn't work"* with a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method. We also use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to clean up any blank spaces (or tabs) at the ends of lines. We don't have to worry about newlines, since `.splitlines` takes care of those.

The idea is that if there are any blank lines or lines just containing whitespace, they will get converted to empty strings by the combined action of `.splitlines` & `.rstrip`. So when we encounter an empty `row`, if we have data in the `inner` buffer we append it to the `nested` output buffer, and create a new empty `inner` buffer. Otherwise, we just append the current `row` to the `inner` buffer. When we get to the end of the data we also need to save any data from `inner` to `nested`.

```
data = '''\
river
mississippi
water
spain
cairo


hellow
kind
words
sentences
'''

nested = []
inner = []
for row in data.splitlines():
    # Remove any trailing whitespace
    row = row.rstrip()
    if row:
        inner.append(row)
    elif inner:
        nested.append(inner)
        inner = []
if inner:
    nested.append(inner)

print(nested)
```

**output**

```
[['river', 'mississippi', 'water', 'spain', 'cairo'], ['hellow', 'kind', 'words', 'sentences']]
```

---

Note that it's easy to adapt this code to reading line by line directly from a file. You don't need to read the whole file into a list before you start work on it. Eg,

```
nested = []
inner = []
with open("test_sets_file") as data:
    for row in data:
        # Remove any trailing whitespace, including newline
        row = row.rstrip()
        if row:
            inner.append(row)
        elif inner:
            nested.append(inner)
            inner = []
    if inner:
        nested.append(inner)

print(nested)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split with [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) the multiple `\n` (`\n\n+` => 2 or more `\n` in a row) and then [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) each part by a single `\n`:

By the way, it's preferable to use [`with`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26342829/1918287) when working with files (for a proper file closing ant context managing):

```
import re

def transform(data):
    return [x.split('\n') for x in re.compile('\n\n+').split(data)]

with open(test_sets_file, 'r') as infile:
    # Read the entire file to a single string
    # data = infile.read()

    # First example
    data = 'river\nmississippi\nwater\nspain\ncairo\n\n\nhellow\nkind\nwords\nsentences'    
    print(transform(data))  # [['river', 'mississippi', 'water', 'spain', 'cairo'], ['hellow', 'kind', 'words', 'sentences']]

    # Second example
    data = 'river\nmississippi\nwater\nspain\ncairo'

    print(transform(data))  # [['river', 'mississippi', 'water', 'spain', 'cairo']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first split based on multiple occurences of `\n` by using a regular expression. Assuming your input is in the variable `string`, we can do the following

```
import re
first_split = re.compile('\n\n+').split(string)
```

Then you can further divide each individual string based on a single `\n`

```
second_split = [x.split('\n') for x in first_split]
```

This yields

```
[['river', 'mississippi', 'water', 'spain', 'cairo'], ['hellow', 'kind', 'words', 'sentences']]
```